# Send specific request multiple times with different parameters using Retrofit & RxJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-viewmodel

I have n EditTexts with their own texts:

editText1 -> text: 13

editText2 -> text: 15

editText3 -> text: 20

...

And there is an API method named as `getNewValue(String currentValue)`. It will get the new value of each EditText due to the current value.

**Scenario:**
`getNewValue()` request will be sent if each EditText get focused and the new value will be set on focused EditText.

**How can I achieve this goal using Retrofit, RxJava and ViewModel?**

I tried this code:

**Fragment:**

```
editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(getEtFocusChangeListener(editText1.getText().toString()));
editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(getEtFocusChangeListener(editText2.getText().toString()));
editText3.setOnFocusChangeListener(getEtFocusChangeListener(editText3.getText().toString()));
```

- 

```
private View.OnFocusChangeListener getEtFocusChangeListener(String currentValue) {
    return (view, hasFocus) -> {
        if (hasFocus) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            viewModel.getNewValue(currentValue);
            viewModel.getNewValueResponse().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), newValue -> et.setText(newValue));
            viewModel.getNewValueError().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), throwable -> Log.i(TAG, "New Value Error -----> " + throwable));
        }
    };
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private final MutableLiveData<String> newValueResponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
private final MutableLiveData<Throwable> newValueError = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

- 

```
public void getNewValue(String currentValue) {
    apiService.getNewValue(currentValue)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull String newValue) {
                    newValueResponse.postValue(newValue);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {
                    newValueError.postValue(throwable);
                }
            });
}

public LiveData<String> getNewValueResponse() {
    return newValueResponse;
}

public LiveData<Throwable> getNewValueError() {
    return newValueError;
}
```

**ApiService:**

```
@GET("Values/GetNewValue")
Single<String> getNewValue(@Query("currentValue") String currentValue);
```

---

One solution is to declare a global variable to save the the last focused `EditText` and use it when the request respond, but I think there is a better & smarter solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Android programing, so sorry if I am missing something and make any mistake, but why don't you pass a reference to the `EditText` that has been focused to the `getNewValue` method?

Consider for instance:

```java
private final MutableLiveData<Pair<EditText, String>> newValueResponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
private final MutableLiveData<air<EditText, Throwable>> newValueError = new MutableLiveData<>();

//...

public void getNewValue(final EditText editText, final String currentValue) {
    apiService.getNewValue(currentValue)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull String newValue) {
                    newValueResponse.postValue(Pair.create(editText, newValue));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {
                    newValueError.postValue(Pair.create(editText, throwable));
                }
            });
}

public LiveData<Pair<EditText, String>> getNewValueResponse() {
    return newValueResponse;
}

public LiveData<Pair<EditText, Throwable>> getNewValueError() {
    return newValueError;
}
```

The `OnFocusChangeListener` will look like the following:

```java
private View.OnFocusChangeListener getEtFocusChangeListener(String currentValue) {
    return (view, hasFocus) -> {
        if (hasFocus) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            viewModel.getNewValue(et, currentValue);
            viewModel.getNewValueResponse().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), newValue -> newValue.first.setText(newValue.second));
            viewModel.getNewValueError().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), throwable -> Log.i(TAG, "New Value Error -----> " + throwable.second));
        }
    };
}
```

In a certain way I found this last code fragment strange, because if you thing about it, due to the asynchronous nature of the API call, the actual result can be for a different `EditText`. Perhaps the problem could me mitigated with something like that:

```java
private View.OnFocusChangeListener getEtFocusChangeListener(String currentValue) {
    return (view, hasFocus) -> {
        if (hasFocus) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            viewModel.getNewValue(et, currentValue);
            viewModel.getNewValueResponse().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), newValue -> {
    // Only perform the operation if the `EditText` is the affected one
    if (et.equals(newValue.first)) {
        newValue.first.setText(newValue.second);
    }
});
            viewModel.getNewValueError().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), throwable -> {
    if (et.equals(throwable.first)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "New Value Error -----> " + throwable.second);
    }
});
        }
    };
}
```

In my opinion, according to the use case, you could get rid of the `newValueResponse` and `newValueError`  `MutableLiveData` instances. For example:

```java
public void getNewValue(final EditText editText, final String currentValue) {
    apiService.getNewValue(currentValue)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull String newValue) {
                    editText.seText(newValue);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "New Value Error -----> " + throwable);
                }
            });
}
```

And:

```java
private View.OnFocusChangeListener getEtFocusChangeListener(String currentValue) {
    return (view, hasFocus) -> {
        if (hasFocus) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            viewModel.getNewValue(et, currentValue);
        }
    };
}
```

Or perhaps more semantically:

```java
public void getNewValue(final String currentValue) {
    return apiService.getNewValue(currentValue)
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

```java
private View.OnFocusChangeListener getEtFocusChangeListener(String currentValue) {
    return (view, hasFocus) -> {
        if (hasFocus) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            viewModel.getNewValue(et, currentValue)
                         .subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                                 compositeDisposable.add(d);
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onSuccess(@NonNull String newValue) {
                                 et.seText(newValue);
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {
                                 Log.i(TAG, "New Value Error -----> " + throwable);
                             }
                         });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Passing a reference to the `EditText` that has been focused to the `getNewValue()` method is a simple and excellent solution that did not occur to me at the time. But it's not a good idea to send server request in View layer in MVVM architecture.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @AlirezaNoorali. Thank you very much. I am glad to see that the answer was helpful. As I told, I apologize if I made any mistake. Yes, I totally agree with you.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much.